# (iphone) nsarray, nsmutablearray retain/release

Tags: iphone, arrays, retain

this is so basic, but quite not sure how to release array object in object-c.

I know that adding an object to array retains the object.
and removing it from an array releases the object.

When I have an array(mutable or not),
does 'releasing the array itself' also removes objects inside the array(therefore sending release to each object)?
Or should I remove the object first and release the array to reverse the operation (which is retaining array and each object in it).

Thank you

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/885839/with-an-nsarray-of-object-references-do-i-explicitly-release-all-objects-in-the

Comment: ah thanks, was sure there must be the same question but couldn't find it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calling `release`  on `NSArray` OR `NSMutableArray` instances will also release it's objects,