# Memory retention of an NSArray of NSDictionaries

Tags: objective-c

I want an ivar that is an ordered list of dictionaries. If I create an `@property` for this NSArray, set to `retain` and then fill it with `NSDictionary` objects, can I "safely" assume these dictionaries are also retained as part of the ivar, or do I need to separately retain these objects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the collection classes will automatically retain the things you put in them. So if you put things in a dictionary and maintain a reference to the dictionary, you can safely use its contents; and if you store this dictionary in a property you can still safely use it. See [this page](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/Collection.html) for more information:

> - They maintain strong references to their contents.

Answer (score 1):

> NSArray retains objects when they're added, and releases them when
>   they're removed or the array is deallocated. Keep this in mind, it's
>   this concept of "ownership" that retain/release memory management is
>   built upon.

[With an NSArray of object references, do I explicitly release all objects in the array or just the array itself?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/885839/with-an-nsarray-of-object-references-do-i-explicitly-release-all-objects-in-the/885928#885928)